# solutions in upper half plane for polynomial-argument theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $P(z)=z^5-12z^2+14$,
prove that there exist 2 solutions to $P(z)=0 $ in $\{Im(z)\ge 0 \}$

I tried using the argument theorem that states $\oint_{\gamma}\frac{p'\left(z\right)}{p\left(z\right)}dz=2\pi i\left(N-P\right) $.

Obviously $P=0 $ because it is a polynomial, I need to prove that $N=2$.

I looked at $$ \begin{cases}
\gamma_{1}=t, & t\in\left[-R,R\right]\\
\gamma_{2}=Re^{it} & t\in\left[0,\pi\right]
\end{cases} $$ and $\gamma =\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 $.

This made the 2 integrals $$ \oint_{\gamma}\frac{p'\left(z\right)}{p\left(z\right)}dz=\int\limits _{-R}^{R}\frac{5t^{4}-24t}{t^{5}-12t^{2}+14}dt+\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}\frac{R^{4}e^{4it}-24Re^{it}}{R^{5}e^{5it}-12R^{2}e^{2it}+14}\cdot iRe^{it}dt $$
$$ \int\limits _{-R}^{R}\frac{5t^{4}-24t}{t^{5}-12t^{2}+14}dt=\ln\left|\frac{R^{5}-12R^{2}+14}{-R^{5}-12R^{2}+14}\right|\xrightarrow{R\to\infty}0 $$
The problem is evaluating $$ \int\limits _{0}^{\pi}\frac{5R^{4}e^{4it}-24Re^{it}}{R^{5}e^{5it}-12R^{2}e^{2it}+14}\cdot iRe^{it}dt\approx\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}\frac{5iR^{5}e^{5it}}{R^{5}e^{5it}}\cdot dt=5\pi i $$.
I used a very loose approximation because I have no idea how to actually integrate that, and this gives me $N=2.5 $, which I think is wrong,I need to get an integer.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: An easier argument: if $z$ is a solution, then so is its conjugate $\overline z$. So, at least half of the zeroes must lie on or above the real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $P(z)$ has at least three roots along the real line because the coefficients of $P$ are real, and
$$P(-2)=-66<0, P(0)=14>0, P(2)=-2<0, P(3)=149>0.$$
Hence, by continuity, there is at least one root in each interval $(-2,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(2,3)$.
This means that your integral
$$\int\limits _{-R}^{R}\frac{P'(t)}{P(t)}\,dt$$
does not make sense because of the denominator which has zeros in the interval $[-R,R]$ for $R>2$. Looking at the zeros of $P'(z)=z(5z^3-24)$ it is easy to verify that all the roots of $P$ are simple.

Moreover the above remark implies that $\{\text{Im}(z)\ge 0 \}$ contains at least four roots of $P$: the three roots along the real line and one of the other two roots (which are conjugate).